# PHP and jQuery upload progress bar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jqueryform

I'm trying to create a progress bar using this [libary](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started).

But I'm getting this error on the most basic example:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined
>       at r.fn.init.e.fn.ajaxSubmit (jquery.form.js:171)
>       at HTMLFormElement.t (jquery.form.js:1026)
>       at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLFormElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)

This is my code:

```
<head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/4.2.2/jquery.form.min.js" integrity="sha384-FzT3vTVGXqf7wRfy8k4BiyzvbNfeYjK+frTVqZeNDFl8woCbF0CYG6g2fMEFFo/i" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


        <script>  
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $('#fileUploadForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
                alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script> 
    </head>

<body>
        <form id="fileUploadForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
            <input type="submit" value="Prenesi">

        </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Is jquery.form.min.js available for sure?  Is jQuery.form 4.2.2 compatible with jQuery 3.2.1?

Comment: Yes, and yes (according to its documentation it's compatible with jQuery 3.x.x)

Answer (score 0):

Your error tells you the exact line in your script where the error is being thrown. You have no success function. Change your code to this and it should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#fileUploadForm').ajaxForm({
        success: function() {  
            alert("Thank you for your comment!");
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I already tried that and it's still not working, displaying the same error.